# jQuery maphighlight for changing area highlight color

Tags: jquery, dictionary, highlight

i am using jquery.maphighlight.min.js plugin for highlighting mapped area...now my problem is to change the highlight color depends upon the condition...In first condtion highlight the area with the red color then the same area will be highlighted with the black color for the second condition.I can able to highlight the same area but i cant able to change the color of the area simultaneously...any one help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> In first condtion highlight the area with the red color then the same area will be highlighted with the black color for the second condition

[Have you checked the documentation](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) and [some of the feature demos](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html)?  It looks like you can simply define the colors when you set up the selectable area, and it looks like you can also over-ride the style information for the specific area inside the area tag itself.  View the source of the demo page.

Comment: i checked the feature demo as well but i can't figured out. can we help a little more help? thanks